# how to accelerate 2D convolution with FFT?

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Zero-pad an image
def zero_pad(image, pad_height, pad_width)：
    H, W = image.shape
    out = np.zeros((H+2*pad_height, W+2*pad_width))
    out[pad_height:H+pad_height,pad_width:W+pad_width] = image
    return out

# An step-by-step implementation of convolution filter
def conv(image, kernel):
    Hi, Wi = image.shape
    Hk, Wk = kernel.shape
    out = np.zeros((Hi, Wi))
    image_pad = zero_pad(image, (Hk-1)//2, (Wk-1)//2)
    for i in range(Hi):
        for j in range(Wi):
            out[i,j] = np.sum(kernel*image_pad[i:Hk+i,j:Wk+j])
    return out

# accelerate convolution using FFT
def conv_faster(image, kernel)： 
    Hi, Wi = image.shape
    Hk, Wk = kernel.shape
    out = np.zeros((Hi, Wi))

    # expand image and kernel by zero-padding
    if( (Hi+Hk) % 2 == 0):
        x = (Hi+Hk)
    else:
        x = (Hi+Hk)-1
    if( (Wi+Wk) % 2 == 0):
        y = (Wi+Wk)
    else:
        y = (Wi+Wk)-1
    image_pad = np.zeros((x,y))
    kernel_pad = np.zeros((x,y))
    image_pad[0:Hi,0:Wi] = image
    kernel_pad[0:Hk,0:Wk] = kernel

    # make image and kernel at the center of frequency domain
    for p in range(Hi):
        for q in range(Wi):
            image_pad[p,q]*=(-1)**(p+q)
    for p in range(Hk):
        for q in range(Wk):
            kernel_pad[p,q]*=(-1)**(p+q)

    # do fft for image and kernel
    image_pad_fft = np.fft.fft2(image_pad)
    kernel_pad_fft = np.fft.fft2(kernel_pad) 


    # get the imaginary part of kernel's transformation
    kernel_pad_fft = 1j*np.imag(kernel_pad_fft)

    # multiply the two in frequency domain
    out_pad = np.fft.ifft2(image_pad_fft*kernel_pad_fft)

    # get he real part of result 
    out = np.real(out_pad[0:Hi,0:Wi])

    # Counteract the preceding centralization
    for p in range(Hi):
        for q in range(Wi):
            out[p,q]*=(-1)**(p+q)
    return out
```

There are some difference between their returns.
I think there result should be same, how could I refine it? Thinks!
the kernel is [[1,0,-1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]]

[image]

I input this image for the two function

[image]

The step-by-step function obtains this result

[image]

The  accelerated function obtains this result

Answer (score 0):

For a convolution, the Kernel must be flipped. What you do in `conv()` is a correlation.
Since your Kernel is symmetric apart from a minus sign, result2 = -result1 in your current results

Comment: after I refined my program by np.flip(),there is still a large L2 distance between two function, I guess it maybe result from spectrum leakage, am I right?

Comment: @xinruli how exactly did you flip it?

Comment: can you update your code and results accordingly? It should be exactly the same

Comment: @xinruli I think you also don't handle the borders correctly in your convolution function